unity accessing child global position from another child, returns local
I'm trying to instantiate bullets from weapon script. I have empty object (weapon child) that is a bullet spawn point, and weapon has it's link. Everything works perfect, except transform.position and transform.localPosition returns the same local coordinates.
It seems like accessing position of a child from another child gives this result, which is my case as weapon is a child of a Player. However accessing bulletSpawnPoint position from Player gives the same result (I'm getting it through code as the weapon is created object). The question is if there are any ways to get global position in my case, or if I need modify my hierarchy?
I figured out that the same code returns different values in Update, versus my public function Shoot. Also if I call Shoot() from update it works fine, but if I call Shoot() from Player script it returns wrong position (probably taken from prefab). Any suggestions?
Images of code and game scene:
ShootingWeapon Class
Accessing position in Player class
Bullets spawning in wrong position in editor

transform.position always gives the worldspace position, the editor's transform component always shows the transform.localPosition. Make 100% sure that "bulletSpawnPoint" is the correct reference in the UnityEditor, that's the only transform that matters in your code

the reference is 100% correct, I'm adding it through weapon prefab editor, there is no access to other objects

So, there is no problem with transform position. The problem was I was getting component from prefab itself, when I changed it to the created instance everything works. Here is a screenshot where was the mistake:
image
